# How to export an object from 3d max studio for use it in THree.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, 3dsmax

I have a problem with loading an object that I have created in 3d studio max!
I export it like an .obj (and it gives me two files, .obj and .mtl). I have used OBJMTLLOADET() didn't worked, I used MTLLOADER() and OBJLOADER() and none of them worked. I used other object and they worked, I think the problem is when I export the object in 3d max.

here are the codes I used to in webgl for loading object:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    loader.addEventListener ('load', function(event)
    {
        objModel = event.content;
        objModel.traverse(function(child)
        {
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh)
            {
                child.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial
                ({
                    color:0xffffff, wireframe: true
                });
            }
        }); 
        objModel.position.y -80;
        scene.add(objModel);
    });
    loader.load('asteroid.obj');
```

Next code:

```
 var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener ('load', function(event){
        objModel = event.content;
        objModel.position.x = 80;
        objModel.position.y = -80;
        objModel.position.z = 0;
        objModel.scale.y = 1;
        objModel.scale.x = 1;
        objModel.scale.z = 1;
        scene.add(objModel);
    });
    loader.load('asteroid.obj','asteroid.mtl');
```

When I use other objets these codes work perfectly, but when I use my object It doesn't work!! Can someone tell me how to export an object from 3d max studio to use it in THree.js ??

NEW EDITED:
Here is the download link for the object:  [Download .obj file](http://www.sendspace.com/file/hvq5gn)

Comment: Can you post the generated obj and mtl files that have a problem?

Comment: I updated the post, in the end you can see the link to download the object.... or just copy the link here: http://www.sendspace.com/file/hvq5gn

Answer (score 1):

Yes the problem is that your export file is comprised of polygons while the current implementation of OBJMTLLoader requires triangles. As a workaround, create triangles when you export using a triangulation flag that I am sure 3dsmax has.